# Symfony2: How use 'ckeditor' in a form?

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, bundle

I installed TRsteelCkeditorBundle, when I'm building in the view a form manually, it works.

```
 <form method="post">
        <p>
            My Editor:<br>
            <textarea name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit">
        </p>
    </form>
```

But when I try to use the Symfony2 form I get this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("Route "route_name" does not exist.") in 
lbTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 8
```

My codes :
In the Twig template
    
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    
    
Ligne 8 is the form_widget

In the controller:

```
  public function indexAction()
  {
  $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder();

  $formBuilder
    ->add('date',        'date')
    ->add('title',       'text')
    ->add('content',     'ckeditor')
    ->add('author',      'text');

  $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
  $view['form'] = $form -> CreateView();

  return $this->render('lbTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $view);
  }
```

I followed step by step the indications of the Read_me.txt in he github page, and try to find answers elsewhere but found nothing. If someone can help me to solve that problem, i'm still beginner with SF2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is at `lbTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 8`?

Obviously you have a route `route_name` in you template which is not defined in you routing.yml file.

That's all the error message says.

Comment: Hello,`{{ form_widget(form) }}` is line 8

Comment: And the error comes when I add the ckeditor field in the form builder `->add('content',     'ckeditor')`

Comment: Finally, it did not come from the routing.yml

Comment: But it was a routing concern

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  Spend all day today researching. 
Finally, fixed it by replacing  the TRsteelCkeditor bundle with the IvoryCKEditor bundle.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it this evening and see the diference.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the error comes from.
the route_name comes from

```
 #config.yml for TrsteelCkeditor
  filebrowser_image_browse_url:
      route: route_name
      route_parameters:
          type: image
```

I suppose I have to put the route where the editor goes when you want to upload images in the editor.
I'll continue to test this budle till I got something fine and I'll give the result

Answer (score 0):

Adding in comment the line

```
#route: route_name
```

In the config.yml solve the problem, this line is for uploading images on the server I think, see this link : 
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)

But now I am having some issues with language, I want to put it in French, at the moment the skin seems language dependent just like the hover on the buttons.

Also if you want to configure it, you can do it either in the config.yml or the config.js in /web/bundle repository if you already install the assets.